# C: Creating a given number of variables automatically

Tags: c, variables

Is it possible to create a C-function that creates automatically a given number of variables? How are variables named?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, it sound like a job for an array.

Comment: I suppose you could do something with a macro, and use another macro to reference the generated variables. Though the question, of course, is why and what!?

Comment: No, but you can create an array dynamically of given number size and use `array[index]` as variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use array.
example:

```
//n is number of variables

int *var;

var=  malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

variables are named var[0], var[1]....var[n-1]
```

Comment: In C, do NOT cast the return value from `malloc()`!! I mean it, don't make come over there and slap you around :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858

Answer (score 3):

Variables are an artifact of your source code. During runtime (which is when your function actually executes) there is only memory and registers. Maybe you want an array of a certain length?

Comment: Well, some symbols are usually exported... in hosted environments

Answer (score 0):

If by "variables" you mean "global variables outside the scope of the function", and by "create" you mean "declare and define", then NO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the register_globals 'feature' in PHP? Thank goodness, no.